custom clipped area out of container , the child is going out of that clipped area
I had made a custom clipper in the shape on pie , and applied it to a container , now when i place some child in that container ,say text() , then it is constrained to that container itsefl not the clipped area by clip path , I want to restrict the child within the clipped area. PFA the code sample

ClipPath(
  clipBehavior: Clip.hardEdge,
  clipper: PieShapeClipper(startAngleDeg: startAngleDeg, sweepAngleDeg: sweepAngleDeg),
  child: Container(
    width: radius,
    height: radius,
    decoration: BoxDecoration(shape: BoxShape.circle),
    child: Text(" i want to check this out."),
  ),
)

[![sample image][1]][1]


this is how ClipPath works, you cannot change that

Hello, can you provide an image of your code result? it can be helpful for us that want to understand the problem. Thanks.

@pskink is there any other way.

yes, custom ShapeBorder where you can override getOuterPath method and dimensions getter but it requires some calculations since it uses EdgeInsets  - btw why dont you simply use CustomPaint?

@gopelkujo i have added ref image please check

@pskink i tried it but it both ways but had encountered dificulties within ,

with CustomPaint? what difficulties? and when it comes to custom ShapeBorder see PieShape

@pskink in custonpaint it still do not restric the child within the shape , thank for shape border will try this out and let you know.

in CustomPaint you have the full control what and where you are drawing - all depends on you, you simply draw multiple arcs and text on top of them

@pskink Thanks for the answer , I previous did used the shapeborder , tha fact i was missing is align and constrainedbox.
